# TypeScript function not inferring generic parameter from super interface

Tags: typescript, generics

This is easiest to explain with code:

```
interface ApiRequest<T> {}
interface SomeRequest extends ApiRequest<string> {
    value: string;
}

function sendRequest<
    TRequest extends ApiRequest<TResponse>,
    TResponse
>(
    request: TRequest
): TResponse {
    return null as TResponse;
}

const x = sendRequest({ value: "a value" } as SomeRequest);

// Type of x is inferred as {} rather than string
x.length;
```

The function sendRequest should infer TResponse from the fact that `SomeRequest` extends `ApiRequest<T>` with `string`, but it doesn't. Instead, it infers `{}` and gives no errors.

How can I do this without explicitly declaring the type parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make more generic type parameters than you have to. If a type parameter only appears once in an input position (i.e. not in the return type and not in two different parameters), reduce it to the non-constrained version:

```
function sendRequest<TResponse>(request: ApiRequest<TResponse>): TResponse {
    return null as TResponse;
}
```

You also need `T` to be manifest somewhere in `ApiRequest`:

```
interface ApiRequest<T> {
    structuralTypingMatters: T;
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that the type parameter won't ever be used in the type. This is generated code from the server and the generic parameter is just indicating what the return type of a request should be. It sounds like that's just not a supported use case in TypeScript?

Comment: If the type parameter isn't in the type, then you don't have a generic type. Unconsumed type parameters don't make any sense in structural type systems. It's like saying an invisible car is green.

Comment: Fair enough. But I'd say more like "If this car had a color, it would be green." The structural nature of TypeScript can be a little unintuitive for those of us coming from nominally-typed languages, especially when doing code generation and trying to represent server-side types on the client. In this case, we decided to add a `"@responseTypeInferenceHelperPleaseDontPutAnythingHere"?: T` variable. It's a hack, but it works, I suppose. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I'm curious though, if you have any ideas of how to represent that type of thing better.